# How to prevent 2 Animation on Object at the same time in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I have a **`UILabel`** and each time it touched, it'll scaled with **`CGAffineTransformMakeScale`** and animation, then back to real size with animation. Now if it touched before last animation ends, it'll scale the scaled object not the real size of main object and so it'll scaled more than it should to be scale. How to prevent this problem ? I want to second touch before last scale ending scale the main size of object.

Here is My Code :

```
(void)MyLabelTouched
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
            MyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
                MyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(void)MyLabelTouched
{ 
   if(animRunning){return;}
   animRunning = YES;
   [ MyLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
    MyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
        MyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
            MyLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            animRunning = NO;
        }];
    }];
 }
```

Comment: yes I tried this but if touched fast it all time remain the main size but I want in this case remain at the scaled size. This solution feels cured animation for the user.